# Однородные члены предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите переделать предложение: Участники конкурса выступали в разных жанрах сценического мастерства: песни, стихи, танцы, инсценировки, литературно-музыкальные композиции. Знаю, однород.члены предложения должны стоять в том же падеже, что и обобщающее слово. Но получается как-то некрасиво: в песнях, танцах...

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Участники конкурса выступали в разных жанрах сценического мастерства: исполняли песни, стихи, танцы, представляли (показывали) инсценировки, литературно-музыкальные композиции.

Comment: Спасибо Вам.

Comment: Если это сценическое мастерство, лучше, на мой взгляд,написать так:  читали стихи. Иначе получится, что участники конкурса пели эти стихи. Хотя смысл,мне кажется, заключается именно в том, что они именно читали.

Answer (score 2):

(выражение, не требующее согласования по падежам)

Участники конкурса выступали в таких жанрах сценического мастерства, как...